# google map api with links on the multi markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

i have been using this: [google maps marker as link api v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837345/google-maps-marker-as-link-api-v3)

what i got is the all the markers in my map has the same link
so i changed the code a bit and nothing helped

**the main thing i'm struggling with is that in the first for loop the var i is between 0 to n but inside the geocoder.gercode function it is always the n value (top value) and not incrising from 0 to n and therefore my link is always the last one**

```
var AllPlaces = new Array();
var address = [<%=LocationStr%>];
var links = [<%=LinkStr%>];
var dolinks = (links.length == 0) ? false : true;
var MaxAddress = address.length;
var ThisLink;
var Markers = new Array();
var Mj = 0;
var geocoder;
function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    for (var i = 0; i < MaxAddress; i++) {
        ThisLink = "";
        Mj = i;
        if (dolinks) {
            ThisLink = links[i];
        }
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address[i]}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                AllPlaces.push(results[0].geometry.location);
                if (MaxAddress == 1) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                }
                else {
                    DoCenter(AllPlaces,map);
                }
                Markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    url: ThisLink, 
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
                alert(Mj);
                if (dolinks) {
                    google.maps.event.addListener(Markers[i], 'click', function() {
                        window.location.href = Markers[i].url;
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng();
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: <%=ZoomStr%>,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        zoomControl: true,
        scaleControl: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }; 
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("<%=DivID%>"), myOptions);
    }

    function DoCenter(LL,obj) {
        if (LL.length < MaxAddress) return;
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();
        for (var i = 0, LtLgLen = LL.length; i < LtLgLen; i++) {
            bounds.extend (LL[i]);
        }
        obj.fitBounds (bounds);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify what was the problem. Your *i* is increasing, but as you know this *i* is a live one. I.e. while you are looping its value is also changing. So for example:

```
var arr = [];
for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
   var func = function() {
      console.log(i);
   }
   arr.push(func);
}

for(var j=0; j<5; j++) {
    arr[j]();
}
```

The result of the code above is:

```
5
5
5
5
5
```

The solution is to create a anonymous function and call it immediately:

```
var arr = [];
for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    var func = function(index) {
        return function() {
            console.log(index);
        }
    }(i);
    arr.push(func);
}
for(var j=0; j<5; j++) {
    arr[j]();
}
```

Comment: can you please explain more about it?

Comment: Yep, sorry I just corrected my code. I have to go now. But when I come back will add additional comment regarding the approach.

Comment: thanks - i managed to fix my code with that and some other example i found

Answer (score 0):

geocoder.geocode run asynchronously. your for loop may finish before first geocode  callback execute. Create a new function to associate each link . 
Note: Each function run in new context.
Modified Code:

```
var AllPlaces = new Array();
var address = [<%=LocationStr%>];
var links = [<%=LinkStr%>];
var dolinks = (links.length == 0) ? false : true;
var MaxAddress = address.length;
var ThisLink;
var Markers = new Array();
var Mj = 0;
var geocoder;
function reversGeoCord(address, ThisLink ){

   geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                AllPlaces.push(results[0].geometry.location);
                if (MaxAddress == 1) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                }
                else {
                    DoCenter(AllPlaces,map);
                }
                Markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    url: ThisLink, 
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
                alert(Mj);
                if (dolinks) {
                    google.maps.event.addListener(Markers[i], 'click', function() {
                        window.location.href = Markers[i].url;
                    });
                }
            }
        });
}
function initialize() {

    for (var i = 0; i < MaxAddress; i++) {
        ThisLink = "";
        Mj = i;
        if (dolinks) {
            ThisLink = links[i];
        }
        reversGeoCord(address[i], ThisLink  );
    }
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng();
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: <%=ZoomStr%>,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        zoomControl: true,
        scaleControl: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }; 
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("<%=DivID%>"), myOptions);
    }

    function DoCenter(LL,obj) {
        if (LL.length < MaxAddress) return;
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();
        for (var i = 0, LtLgLen = LL.length; i < LtLgLen; i++) {
            bounds.extend (LL[i]);
        }
        obj.fitBounds (bounds);
}
```