# Jquery google maps linking with iPhone maps

Tags: jquery, iphone, google-maps

im making an iphone web based app and i have embedded a google maps with a place marker for a shop and i want to know how you make it so when the user taps on it, it loads up google maps app and allows them to navigate to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually quite simple, just put your google map inside a link to the actual location in google maps, like so:

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=12131408883620679552&amp;q=Chelsea+Market,+New+York,+NY,+United+States&amp;hl=en&amp;ved=0CBMQ-gswAA&amp;sa=X&amp;ei=AbqjTvjcBILmygTh2tjPCQ&amp;sig2=zXJOwK02xhQK3vS7iyA56A" target="_blank" class="gmap">
                <img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Chelsea+Market,+New+York,+NY,+United+States&amp;zoom=13&amp;size=470x220&amp;sensor=false&amp;markers=color:black%7Clabel:S%7C40.74362,-74.00726">
            </a>
```

When the user clicks, Google Maps will kick in.

Comment: yeah ive tried that when the i tap the map it just opens safari and goes to the google maps i want it to open the google maps app on the iPhone

Comment: weird, I have that exact piece of code working for a customer's app and when I try it on my iPhone it goes straight to Google Maps app, weird...

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a [URL Scheme Reference for Map Links](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html) that describe this.

A link as simple as this would work.  I just tested it to be sure.

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=London">London</a>
```

Here's also a discussion of setting the [Map Marker link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837345/google-maps-marker-as-link-api-v3).

Comment: thats really good thanks
i was wondering how you can get it to display the map swell in say a 100x100 iframe